# C Windows: generate a child process in order to stop and restart (after timeout) the parent process

Tags: c, windows, fork, createprocess

i have to realize a program that, among other things, have to kill itself (in response to a received command) and restart after a timeout set before abort; moreover it have to log that the restart is due to this kind of operation. In linux this could be done quite easily using a fork and managing the different pid, but unfortunately i have to realize this program in windows, using plain C. I have read several article, saying that a clone of fork in windows is a real pain. I have tried to understand createProcess but it appears not so indicated in this case. A solution could be realize a second program and passing it the timeout trough createProcess and command line argument but it is a soultion that i wish to avoid if possible.

Comment: command line probably best solution, unless you want to used a named pipe and have process read from stdin.

Comment: Thankx @garr-godfrey

Answer (score 0):

If you need the `fork()` semantics, then your options are:

1. [Windows Subsystem on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about), which already has a fork()
2. [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), which also has a fork()
3. Write your own... this is *not* easy... at all

If you can "cheat", an option would be to create and kill *threads* instead of processes. For transient data, you can use TLS (Thread Local Storage).

Another cheat would be to create a dump file. Say, save a file with [MiniDumpWriteDump](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680360(v=vs.85).aspx) before terminating a process, later read it with [MiniDumpReadDumpStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680359(v=vs.85).aspx) when starting a new process. This is also not so easy and it fails if you rebuild your application and use an old dump file. But, at least it's a well known Windows API.

If none of the above works for you, the only remaining option is to use CreateProcess(), which is a spawn(), not a fork(), then add code to support the fork() features that you need.